# Getting Sum Using PL/SQL In Optimized Way

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have the below PL/SQL block which would be converted to a function, this would be used very heavily, is there a better and efficient way to re-write in the most optimized way?

Appreciate any suggestions or insights.

```
DECLARE
   ln_grand_total   NUMBER;
   ln_total         NUMBER;
   ln_final_total   NUMBER;

   CURSOR E1
   IS
      SELECT SUM (qty * price * rate)
        INTO ln_total
        FROM maximo.po_lines pl
             JOIN maximo.po_headers ph ON pl.HEADER_ID = ph.HEADER_ID
       WHERE ph.HEADER_ID = 0123;
BEGIN
   OPEN E1;

   FETCH E1 INTO ln_grand_total;

   ln_final_total := ROUND (ln_grand_total, 2);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (ROUND (ln_grand_total, 2));

   CLOSE E1;

   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('ln_final_total --> ' || ln_final_total);
END;
/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a cursor for this:

```sql
DECLARE
   ln_total NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT ROUND( SUM (qty * price * rate), 2 )
  INTO   ln_total
  FROM   maximo.po_lines pl
         JOIN maximo.po_headers ph
         ON pl.HEADER_ID = ph.HEADER_ID
  WHERE  ph.HEADER_ID = 0123;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('ln_final_total --> ' || ln_total);
END;
/
```

Answer (score 2):

Indeed there's no problem with the logic, but change the style such as

- if `HEADER_ID` is column of numeric type, then remove the preceding
  zero of `0123`, otherwise quote that as `'0123'`
- `INTO` clause cannot be used for a cursor definition. Eg. get rid of
  `INTO ln_total`. So remove that local variable
- Convert `SUM (qty * price * rate)` within the query of the cursor to

  `ROUND(SUM (qty * price * rate),2)`. So, get rid of `ln_final_total`
  local variable

Therefore, you can use the below code block

```
DECLARE
  ln_grand_total NUMBER(10,2);

 CURSOR E1 IS
 SELECT ROUND( SUM(qty * price * rate), 2)
   FROM maximo.po_lines pl
   JOIN maximo.po_headers ph
     ON pl.HEADER_ID = ph.HEADER_ID
  WHERE ph.HEADER_ID = '0123';
BEGIN
  OPEN E1;
  FETCH E1
   INTO ln_grand_total;
  CLOSE E1;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ln_grand_total --> ' || ln_grand_total);
END;
/
```